# Rellenar informacion especifica de una pagina php a otra

Tags: php, mysql, web

buenas. Ando practicando php y me tope con una problemática que no puedo resolver.
Yo tengo una pagina index.php en la cual tengo una serie de productos con su href la cual lleva a otra pagina producto.php. En esta ultima tengo el producto organizado con un titulo, imagenes, etc. Quiero lograr que al dar click en un producto del index.php tome esa informacion del producto de la tabla de mysql y rellene los campos de titulo imagenes, etc en producto.php pero no se me ocurre como plantear la logica del codigo. Este es el codigo que tengo

/// 1 - index  ///

```
  <?php
  $sentancia = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `juegos`");
  $sentancia->execute();
  $listaJuegos = $sentancia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
  ?>
  <?php foreach ($listaJuegos as $juego) { ?>
    <div class="card m-2" style="width: 16rem;">

      <a href="gamex.php?=<?php echo $juego['titulo'] ?>"><img height="250px" src="<?php echo $juego['img']; ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $juego['titulo']; ?></h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="gamex.php?=<?php echo $juego['titulo'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary">go somewhere</a> 
      </div>
    </div>

  <?php } ?>

</div>
```

/// 2 - producto ///
Aqui es donde me gustaria rellenar los campos img , h1, etc con los datos del producto elegido en index.php pero no se me cae una idea de como lograrlo.

```
<div class="container">

    <h1 class="text-center" style="text-decoration: underline;"><?php echo $titulo; ?></h1>

    <div class="text-center">
        <img src="" class="w-50 p-3" alt="">
    </div>
    <br>
    <nav class="d-flex justify-content-center w-100">
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">General</button>
            <button class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Imagenes</button>
            <button class="nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Descarga</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
            ...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
            ...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
            ...</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

desde ya muchas gracias!.

Comment: Puedes enviar los parametros via Get en el href y luego capturarlos con la variable $_GET. O sólo pasa el id del juego y luego vuelves a cargar esos datos desde la BBDD